# Pre-written code for apps that display text alone?

Tags: android

I am inquiring about pre-written code for apps that display text alone anywhere on the internet or on here. I am curious because it has taken me over a year to read up to 125 pages of a C++ Primer book and I eventually found it a fruitless pursuit and set it aside, only to discover that C++ is a highly specialized language by someone who responded to a related thread on another forum. So, I thought I would inquire about pre-written code on the internet to save myself tremendous heartache and just create my app never to return to C++ again.

I downloaded Lazarus and inquired about GUIs and C++ text but to no avail. Hopefully someone here can shed light on the subject.

Thank you.

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking - what does "text alone anywhere on the internet or on here" mean, exactly.

Also, while C++ can be a bit complex, it is not "highly specialized", and is in fact of fairly general use. But, that said, most (say, 99.9%) of Android apps are not written in C++. It's generally either Java or Kotlin.
But please give us more detail about what you are looking for.

Comment: I was hoping to create an app but I felt it was hopeless to attempt to comprehend the more advanced topics in C++ let alone using it to create my million dollar app whose name I conceived of when I was ^. So I am putting forth my question to anyone who can assist me in actually doing the nitty-gritty coding of the app which aims to display text.